# How can I fix the columns of this website?

Tags: html, css, rows

| Description | Image |
| --- | --- |
| How my website looks right now (No margins on sides) | [image] |
| How it should look | [image] |

I'm not sure what is causing this issue, I really have no clue.

```css
#moto {
  font-size: 48px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #484848;
  margin: 60px 0;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}

#moto span {
  color: #FF5A5F !important;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  max-height: 970px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: yellow;
}

@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .row {
    padding: 0 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- MOTO-->
<div class="row">
  <h1 id="moto"><span>Where to?</span> Start your next trip with<br /> Great Danes.</h1>
</div>
```

idk what else to say, idk whats wrong or where to start, it was working until this point

https://youtu.be/k4q5kM90zvY?t=207

THIS is the YT video I am following, pls tell me how to work it like him

Comment: You posted a few CSS selectors. We need a [mcve]

Comment: Also post some `html` don't make others do a extra work which you can easily provide

Comment: OKAY. @Rana  done

Comment: @j08691 what did u edit?

Comment: In row class you are providing ```marign: 0 auto``` which is causing no space at left or right. try to set some margin  like this  ```margin: 0 40px```

Answer (score 0):

by looking at your code and the pictures you posted, I believe you would like the .row element to be centered and aligned, like in the second picture. For that, edit your .row element in your css stylesheet. Try this, I believe that is what you are looking for:

```
    #moto {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #484848;
  margin: 60px 0;
  padding-top:5px;
  padding-bottom:5px;
  letter-spacing: 0.8px;
}

#moto span {
  color: #FF5A5F !important;
  font-weight: 700;
}


     .row{
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 80%;
      background-color: yellow;
    }

@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .row {
    padding: 0 15px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

If you are just starting out with HTML and CSS, check out Bootstrap, it's a framework that will ease your whole work process with HTML and CSS, it's very easy and cool to use, also it's the world's most used framework. Check it out here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: https://youtu.be/k4q5kM90zvY?t=207 this is the video i am following for reference.

Comment: That's great, if you tried my code, did it work the way you wanted it to? Do you need more help?

Comment: Hi @Vladmir B. It did work but im not sure it is a permanent fix, if u click that youtube link it will clearly show the problem I am getting vs how he is doing it properly.